# Hotchocolate Filter by BsonExtraElements

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, graphql, hotchocolate

We have next entity:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public Dictionary<string, object?> AdditionalData { get; set; } = new();
}
```

This entity can have many dynamic data that can be stored inside `AdditionalData` property. Using attribute `BsonExtraElements` we can save these data to `MongoDb` perfectly. Our data will be stored as separated properties. It is exactly what we want to save on Storage Level.

After it we implemented all steps described in [instruction](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/integrations/mongodb).

So we designed next `ObjectType`:

```
public class ProductType : ObjectType<Product>
{
    private readonly List<EntityFieldDescriptor> _fields;

    public ProductType(ICollection<EntityFieldDescriptor> fields)
    {
        // There provided our "dynamic" properties for specific entity
        _fields = fields;
    }

    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Product> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(f => f.Id).ID().Name("id");       
        descriptor.Field(f => f.Name).Name("name");       
        descriptor.Ignore(entity => entity.AdditionalData);

        foreach (var field in _fields)
        {
            descriptor
                .Field(field.Name)
                .Type(Type.GetType(field.ValueType)!)
                .Resolve(resolver => resolver.Parent<Product>().AdditionalData.GetValueOrDefault(field.Name));
        }

        descriptor.BindFieldsImplicitly();
    }
}
```

And query:

```
public partial class Query
{
    [UseProjection]
    [UseSorting]
    [UseFiltering]
    public IExecutable<Product> GetProducts(
        [Service] IMongoCollection<Product> collection)
    {
        return collection.AsExecutable();
    }

    [UseFirstOrDefault]
    public IExecutable<Product> GetProductById(
        [Service] IMongoCollection<Product> collection,
        [ID(nameof(Product))] Guid id)
    {
        return collection.Find(x => x.Id == id).AsExecutable();
    }
}
```

And service registration:

```
services.AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddType<ProductType>()
    .AddQueryType<Query>()
    .AddMongoDbFiltering()
    .AddMongoDbSorting()
    .AddMongoDbProjections()
    .AddMongoDbPagingProviders();
```

Using this configuration we can work with predefined properties very well.
We can run next query perfectly:

```
query { 
  products(where: { name: { eq: "test" }}) {
      id,
      material # It is our "dynamic" field
  }
}
```

Our goal is to use "dynamic" field inside `where` clause. Example: where: {**material**: { eq: "cuprum" }}

Of course our filter schema knows nothing about "dynamic" fields. So we defined next `FilterInputType` very similar to `ObjectType`:

```
public class ProductFilterType : FilterInputType<Product>
{
    private readonly List<EntityFieldDescriptor> _fields;

    public ProductFilterType(ICollection<EntityFieldDescriptor> collection)
    {
        // There provided or "dynamic" properties for specific entity
        _fields = fields;
    }

    protected override void Configure(IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<Product> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(f => f.Code).Name("code");
        descriptor.Ignore(entity => entity.AdditionalData);

        foreach (var field in _fields)
        {
            descriptor.Field(field.Name).Type(typeof(StringOperationFilterInputType));
        }

        descriptor.BindFieldsImplicitly();
    }
}
```

After creation of this `FilterInputType` we will be able to run our GraphQL query to server.
But when `Hotchocolate` run our query then we have an error:
[image]

Is it possible to use **filtration/sorting/pagination** of `BsonExtraElements` using `Hotchocolate` library?

Will be grateful for any help!